# Kibana returns “Connection Failed” - Unsolved Error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I ham trying to setup ElasticSearch, Logstash and Kibana on the same machines. I have set up :

elasticsearch-1.4.0
logstash-1.4.2
kibana-3.1.2

I have followed all the steps according to this article: http://aarvik.dk/a-bit-on-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-the-elk-stack/

I have ElasticSearch running and I'm able to run simple queries against it.

However, when I try accessing the Kibana, I get the following message:

> Connection Failed
>   Possibility #1: Your elasticsearch server is down or unreachable
>
> This can be caused by a network outage, or a failure of the Elasticsearch process. If you have ?recently run a query that required a terms facet to be executed it is possible the process has run out of memory and stopped. Be sure to check your Elasticsearch logs for any sign of memory pressure.
>   Possibility #2: You are running Elasticsearch 1.4 or higher
>
> Elasticsearch 1.4 ships with a security setting that prevents Kibana from connecting. You will need to set http.cors.allow-origin in your elasticsearch.yml to the correct protocol, hostname, and port (if not 80) that your access Kibana from. Note that if you are running Kibana in a sub-url, you should exclude the sub-url path and only include the protocol, hostname and port. 
>   Click back, or the home button, when you have resolved the connection issue

I know other users have faced similar problems and I followed the suggestions mentioned in: [Kibana returns "Connection Failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828099/kibana-returns-connection-failed)

I have added

> http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
>
> http.cors.enabled: true

to the elasticsearch.yml. I still see the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am having the same problem but only appears once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused because of two issues.

1. Please check you are using compatible versions of Elasticsearch and Kibana. Recommended to use latest versions of both.
   elasticsearch-1.4.4 and kibana-4.0.0-rc1-windows worked for me.
2. This is little interesting. If you are using logstash and if one of your job is still running then Kibana gives error in  that case.

You can refer to these articles for more details

http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/install-elasticsearch-kibana-logstash-on-windows.html

http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/log-analytics-using-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana.html