# Upgrade Required Your version of Elasticsearch is too old. Kibana requires Elasticsearch 0.90.9 or above

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed kibana and elastic search on my server but its throwing error

```
Upgrade Required Your version of Elasticsearch is too old. Kibana requires Elasticsearch 0.90.9 or above.
```

but the result I am getting as the output of

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/_all/process?pretty
```

is

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "YZdakphGSruLIQUz332paA" : {
      "name" : "Grandmaster",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.36:9300]",
      "hostname" : "arun-HCL-ME-Laptop",
      "version" : "0.90.9",
      "http_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.36:9200]",
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 1000,
        "id" : 6398,
        "max_file_descriptors" : 65535,
        "mlockall" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do a little more by adding to elasticsearch-1.4 the following parameters in elasticsearch.yml

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

See: [Kibana returns "Connection Failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828099/kibana-returns-connection-failed/26884367#26884367)
OR https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2056

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

this error happened because you configure the URL to your Elasticsearch server not correct. It should be refer to Elastichsearch host in kibana3/config.js file

```
elasticsearch: "http://192.168.0.36:80", // your IP
```

If you use domain to browser kibana, please change IP to domain.

```
elasticsearch: "http://domain:80"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened because  in kibana config.js file the port mentioned was 80
then I changed it to.

```
elasticsearch: "http://"+window.location.hostname+":9200"
```